# How to pass the label of an action bar

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm new to Android developing with Java, in my `MainActivity` I have many buttons (Show Types, Show Materials, etc..) and when I click on one of them I go to another activity `DataActivity` but in `DataActivity` where I display my data I want the label in the action bar to be named after the type of data I'm displaying (Types, Materials...), I'm using this method now (for example when I click the Show Types button):

`MainActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DataActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("tableName", "Types");
startActivity(intent);
```

`DataActivity`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
tableName = intent.getStringExtra("tableName");
setTitle(tableName);
```

And it works! but if from `DataActivity` I moved to a new Activity then I went back to the `DataActivity` the action bar is empty now and it doesn't display the `tableName`. how can I solve this?

Comment: When you move to new Activity, did you finish() the activity?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine no. I just move to it in the same way I did from MainActivity to DataActivity, and I'm going back to the DataActivity using the arrow in the action bar.

Answer (score 0):

Could make `tableName` static. I think this would work for you?

```
private static String tableName;

[...]

if (intent.getStringExtra("tableName") != null){
   // tableName was passed by intent
   tableName = intent.getStringExtra("tableName");
   setTitle(tableName);
} else if (tableName != null) {
   // tableName is non-null, but was not passed by intent.
   setTitle(tableName);
} else {
   // No passed tableName, tableName is null
   // Could throw an error here
}
```